# Why do I need 'd=0'in my r script for searching prime number?

Tags: r

I am a beginner in r language.
I was trying to find prime number with r language, and I found a solution in this site.
But I still can't understand some of the process.
Can any expert in r help me with this??
This is the script I saw.

```
d=0
primeno<- c(2:100)

for (i in 2:length(primeno)) {

    for (j in 1:i) {
       if (i %% j == 0) {
           d=d+1
       }
    }

    if (d==2) {
        print(i)
        print ("Prime")
    }

    d <- 0

}
```

I just can't understand why I need 'd=0','d=d+1' and the last 'd=0'in this script.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, it's important to realize prime numbers, p, have 2 factors, 1 and itself (p). Notice a variable that must equal 2? We will get back to it. So, what's `i`, `j`, and `d`? Outer loop => iterate through `i` where `i` is [2-99]. `i` is the number you want to check -- is it prime? Inner loop => iterate through `j` where `j` is [1-`i`]. Let's say `i` is 5 in a round (iteration). Then, `j` will equal 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 during that round.

Comment: Anytime `i` is factorized by `j` => increase `d+1`. So, `d` keeps count of how many factors of `i` there are. Since we are testing many `i`s independently, we need to initiate the counter, `d = 0`, and reset the counter `d <- 0` after each round of `i`.

Comment: Wow....!!!!!!!!! Thank you sooooooo much!!!!!! Since I am a real beginner, it would take some time to understand just with words, but you kindly showed some examples, and I could fully understand with them. This script has been torturing me for days, and I am so released now. Thank you very much, CPak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round 1 (outer loop)

```
d=0
i=2
(round 1 - inner loop)
  j=1
  (2 %% 1 == 0) == True
  d=1
(round 2 - inner loop)
  j=2
  (2 %% 2 == 0) == True
  d=2
(d == 2) == True
  print('Is Prime')
reset d=0
```

Round 2 (outer loop)

```
d=0 (reset after Round 1)
i=3
(round 1 - inner loop)
  j=1
  (3 %% 1 == 0) == True
  d=1
(round 2 - inner loop)
  j=2
  (3 %% 2 == 0) == False
  d=1
(round 3 - inner loop)
  j=3
  (3 %% 3 == 0) == True
  d=2
(d == 2) == True
  print('Is Prime')
reset d=0
```

Round 3 (outer loop)

```
d=0 (reset after Round 2)
i=4
(round 1 - inner loop)
  j=1
  (4 %% 1 == 0) == True
  d=1
(round 2 - inner loop)
  j=2
  (4 %% 2 == 0) == True
  d=2
(round 3 - inner loop)
  j=3
  (4 %% 3 == 0) == False
  d=2
(round 4 - inner loop)
  j=4
  (4 %% 4 == 0) == True
  d=3
(d == 2) == False
  no print
reset d=0
```